Letting Go of Accelerator under 35mph - Grinding Sound By DriveTrain - 2011 Honda Accord LX
I’ve got a 2011 Honda Accord LX, and I’m noticing a strange noise when I let off the accelerator under 35mph. It’s a kind of knocking or grinding sound coming from around the drivetrain area.
I attached a video, but it’s definitely louder in person. Has anyone else experienced this? Any idea what might be causing it? Thanks in advance for any advice!
video of sound

Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! It's hard to tell exactly, but it sounds like you might have a dragging brake or even a really bad wheel bearing. I'd suggest the noise is there all the time but you don't hear it well when the vehicle is under acceleration due to engine noise.
